# ItemId in UserControl

Tags: sitecore

I would like to rephrase situation:
I have two data templates, one for product with tab, second for article with / without tab, using product and article data template respectively. Considering Tab Feature Data Template will act global, where it can be plugged with any Data Template at any point of time.

Now the situation is such I have associated Tab feature with Product but not with Article so outcome should be such that on Product Page I should be viewing the tab feature whereas on Article tab should not be visible.

Question still stands: How would I check in which pages I have plugged Tab Feature? Also How to find the ItemID of the current context page I am currently on?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the code below. It will give you the current Sitecore Item used in the context.

```
Sitecore.Context.Item
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have have assigned different data templates to the content items then you can check the data template on which the item is based with code like this: (It may be better to do it this way than just checking the ItemId)

```
        Sitecore.Data.Items.Item current = Sitecore.Context.Item;
        if (current.TemplateName.Equals("products", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
        {
            // your logic for products items
        }
        else
        {
            // your logic for services items
        }
```

However, if you just want the ItemId you can use code like this:

```
        Sitecore.Data.Items.Item current = Sitecore.Context.Item;
        Sitecore.Data.ID myID = current.ID;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: In using the code: Sitecore.Data.Items.Item current = Sitecore.Context.Item;
        Sitecore.Data.ID myID = current.ID; It is giving me the itemid for my "Home". So it actually does not solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few scenarios that occur to me, not sure which one is yours:

**1. Current Item is the Only Item**

If you are doing something like a details page that shows a product or a services item's full details, the Sitecore.Context.Item call will get you the current item that is in context, in most cases based on the current item path in the URL (there are ways to change the context, but let's ignore those fringe cases for now).  Then you can just bind your fields or extract values just as you would any other time.

**2. Binding to a list of Items**

If you are doing something like a list of "things" (i.e. a .NET repeater bound to a list of items that could be Product or Services) and want to display each one with a user control.  A few options:

1. Add a property to your control (something like "DataSource") and during your repeater databinding in your sublayout set the user control Datasource property (or do so in the repeater markup)
2. Extract the properties you want from the Item during the repeater databinding in your sublayout and pass that to different properties on your user control.

**3. Driven by Datasource**

If you are running a sublayout which is configured to have a Datasource, then you can't use the context item as that will refer to the item bound to the "page" being displayed, and not the particular component you are working on.  In this case, you'll need code like the following to extract the datasource from the current sublayout:

```
var dataSourceId = ((Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControl)Parent).DataSource;
```

(Note: You may want to do some error handling on the above code to prevent null reference errors)

Comment: I would like to rephrase my question: